# Updated Paypal API Reference for PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to call a single Payout using PHP with the Paypal API SDK.

The [API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts) only has curl examples for Payout but when switching to the PHP tab (or any other language at the top of this page for that matter) there is no example code.

Where do I find the API Reference for the PHP SDK? I need information on the classes the sdk invokes. Perhaps it simply doesn't exist but I would like confirmation before going around the SDK and using curl lib.

Comment: Did you try to read the files of the SDK? Here are some screens of my installation (but I dont do payouts): http://i.imgur.com/zhas3bq.png -> http://i.imgur.com/hTiciUe.png seems to be in a quite good naming-order.

Comment: Before posting I searched for Payout in my folders. Paypal recommended I use Composer to install v1.5 of the api and it looks nothing like your folder structure. http://imgur.com/1ETo2Nc , http://imgur.com/4MQD491

Comment: Well... This is my source: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/lib/PayPal . And it looks like this when I show my folder-tree: http://i.imgur.com/bMnZXHK.png I did not use an autoloader or composer and thatwhy had to include all those class-files one by one. But it works and PHP complains on every class it cannot find, until you define it. (http://i.imgur.com/2XVeudK.png and here http://i.imgur.com/G0CQjJb.png)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. You have a subfolder of what I have. Installation issues aside the original question is "where is the documentation for PHP?". I'm going to assume that it doesn't exist (for PHP at least).

Answer (score 2):

This should be the reference you are looking for:

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#payouts

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payouts/CreateSinglePayout.html

Comment: I mean, those are "samples" which seem to expose enough information to use it. Combining these examples with the API reference I get most of what I need.

Comment: When working with Paypal be careful. The sandbox is a US-Account. If you are in germany or another country your live-version could look a bit different. And you might get different objects back from paypal. I had many problems with missing email-addresses. Sometimes there is no customer-email at all. After execution there is one. Sometimes there is a customer email before execution but it vanishes after execution. Such are really stupid bugs you should somehow cover. The same goes for the tax-field, the billing-address-fields and price-info within or without the transaction-object. Its Random!

Comment: Part of the problem was that PayPal's documentation was outdated (and as of this comment and a tech support ticket closure STILL out of date). Their composer.json referenced  their first release 0.5.*  It should be 1.6.*  It helps when you're using the latest code. I doubt Paypal will update their documentation

Answer (score 1):

The REST API doesn't provide the same sort of API reference.  I would recommend using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead, which coincides with [this API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/).

Comment: Have been attempting to integrate PayPal API for 2 days. Your library took me 30 mins. No joke. Wow, nicely done.

Comment: Nice to know! Thanks!